# C sharp to Java : MemoryStream and BinaryReader

Tags: java, c#, memorystream, binaryreader

I am working on a network device and catching packets from it over network as UDP. In some parts i need to parse a byte array (packetBuffer) to get session header but i couldn't. I found a part of code but unfortunatelly it is C sharp and i also couldn't convert it to java. It is like below;

```
MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(packetbuffer);
BinaryReader binreader = new BinaryReader(memstream);

byte[] sessionheader = binreader.ReadBytes(4);
ushort ROapdu_type = correctendianshortus(binreader.ReadUInt16());
```

I need to find what MemoryStream and BinaryReader in C# equivalent in Java is.

I appreciate for all your helps.

Comment: Is your question how the receiver in java would look like?

Comment: Like that, actually, the question is that how can I implement same code in Java?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use [getData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getData()) to get byte[], then extract 4 bytes from the result array and use [ByteBuffer.wrap(result4Byte).getInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt()) to convert it into int(you may need to use order to set byte [ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order(java.nio.ByteOrder)) to little/big endian)